# Hibernate, manyToMany relation with saved and unsaved object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an association Many To Many with A and B objects in my code, the B object of the relation is registered in table "B" in the database, where there are two colums, id and name. The thing is I have 38 B objects that are usually used to associate with A, they have an id from 1 to 38 and they can be choosen by the user, they can't be changed but someone can add an object B and it save it in table B with auto incremental id to associate it with A. So the matter is I how can I do to associate A with a saved or an unsaved B object when I save A?

Here is my code:
Class A

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A", catalog="sist", schema = "")
public class A implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@Basic(optional=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idA;

@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name="AB", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idA")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idB")})
private List<B> bs = new ArrayList();

}
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="B", catalog="sist", schema = "")
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {

 @Id
 @Basic(optional=false)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer idB;
 private String nombre;

 @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="bs")
 private List<A> as = new ArrayList();
}
```

Here is how I save A in a DAO class:

```
public void actualizarMedida(A a) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        sesion = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = sesion.beginTransaction();
        sesion.persist(a);
        tx.commit();
        sesion.flush();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        manejaExcepcion(he);
        throw he;
    } finally {
        sesion.close();
    }
}
```

Now I can save new B objects and associate them with A, but i can't associate A with an existing B object. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate  `List<A>` inside `B` entity with `@JoinTable` annotation too, also provide `getter` and `setter`s

```
@JoinTable(name="AB", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idB")})
private List<A>;
//getter and setters.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But i get the same result, i can save the relation with unsaved object, but if I try to associate A with saved object of B I get this exception
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.project.dominio.B